# Change Chrome notification positions

Tags: google-chrome, 14.10, chromium

Chrome notifications on Windows/Mac show up in the bottom right, but on Ubuntu it is the top right. How can I change this? Does Chromium do it differently?

Answer (score -1):

You sadly don't have a way to control the position. at least yet.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ZipDRLuxFZw

Comment: That thread is from 2013. You couldn't find anything more recent?